# Multi-lines sent from html is not writing in pdf using fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I have textarea field in html which stores address information with multi lines (enter key pressed). I am sending that to a PHP file which then, the PHP file creates a PDF file using fpdf.php. Everything is fine except the addresses are printed in a single line in PDF file... Please help me.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: sample `$newadd = nl2br(str_replace("\n\r", ' ', $inputSafe['address']));`

Comment: $pdf->Text(30, 120, $address);

Comment: what is $inputsafe??

Comment: Show us your code and tell us what you've tried so far. Is the input is echo-ed well in php before exporting it to pdf?

Comment: @srinivasan change it your input address variable and then add `$newadd` for pdf

Comment: i tried that too. i tried this also. not working. $newadd = nl2br($address);

  $newadd = str_replace("<br />" , "\r\n" , $newadd);

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after lots of search and R&D... you have to use write method in fpdf to solve this.. Thanks for time friends